# How to do prune in "A Structured Self-Attentive Sentence Embedding" paper

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp

This paper "A Structured Self-Attentive Sentence Embedding" https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.03130 mentioned pruning in Appendix A.  I looked at all available implementation in GitHub, none does this.

I don't understand how it's done by reading the paper.  Is there implementation or explanation of how this can be done?

Thanks.